# Raincloud plot with confidence

Tags: r, plot, confidence-interval, violin-plot, ggdist

I am trying to create a raincloud plot with a 95% confidence interval, however my code keeps on produces a raincloud plot with a boxplot interval. Meaning the black circle is the median not the mean. How can I change my code to add in error bars to achieve this?

Here are two codes I tried that create the raincloud plot, but no with the mean. I have attached how the plots look. The last image is how I want the plot to look.
")

```
Can be found here:
https://z3tt.github.io/Rainclouds/
```

ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Width)) +
ggdist::stat_halfeye(adjust = .5, width = .3, .width = c(0.5, 1)) +
ggdist::stat_dots(side = "left", dotsize = .4, justification = 1.05, binwidth = .1)

Comment: Need an actual data object. Not just code that isn't yet doing what you desire. Also need `library` calls for all necessary packages that are not in the base or Recommended sets.

Comment: Hello user21215346. Typically questions are asked with data available, or put into a form that uses internal R datasets. For example, perhaps you can use the `diamonds` dataset that comes with R so that anyone who would like to help you figure out your issue can do so without wondering what your data looks like. You can also use  `dput(df)` and paste the result into your question (if it isn't too long). Or, sample the data down to a small sample then use `dput()`.

Comment: @IRTFM thanks for the feedback, i just added data that is easily accessible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for updating your question with a minimal reproducible example. One potential 'easy' solution is to add the mean to the existing plot:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggdist)

iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Petal.Length, y=Species))+
  stat_slab(aes(fill=Species), scale = 0.7) +
  stat_dotsinterval(aes(fill=Species),
                    side = "bottom",
                    scale = 0.7,
                    slab_size = NA) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
  stat_summary(aes(color = "mean"), 
               fun=mean, geom="point", shape="|", size=5) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16) +
  theme(legend.position = "top")+
# scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-4.5, .5), breaks = seq(-4.5, 0.5, by = 0.5))+
  labs(title="Raincloud plot with ggdist") +
  scale_color_manual(name = "",
                     values = c("mean" = "cyan"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

If this doesn't suit, I suspect you need to calculate the statistics yourself, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggdist)
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(mean = mean(Petal.Length),
         se = sd(Petal.Length)/sqrt(length(Petal.Length))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Petal.Length, y=Species)) +
  stat_slab(aes(fill = Species)) +
  stat_dots(side = "bottom", shape = 16) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(xmin = mean - 1.96 * se,
                    xmax = mean + 1.96 * se), width = 0.2) +
  stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="point", shape=16, size=2.5) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16) +
  theme(legend.position = "top")+
  # scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-4.5, .5), breaks = seq(-4.5, 0.5, by = 0.5))+
  labs(title="Raincloud plot with ggdist")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thanks for answering this! It did add the mean, however how can i balance out the confidence interval? The mean is on the way left as oppose to the middle. I will add a photo of what i mean.

Comment: Extreme outliers can disproportionately impact the mean e.g. median 'wealth per capita' in the US is $93,271 and the mean is $579,051 (having billionaires skews the distribution). This is often why median/quartiles/whiskers are used to describe a distribution. This is also why I think my first answer is a good option: you have the boxplot information as well as the 'potentially informative' mean. You might also have something wrong with your code. If you can share your actual data and code I could take a look. If it's too big for SO, you can dump it in https://pastebin.com/ and post the link.

Comment: for some reason the second iris code you adapted is not formatted correctly. When i enter it in on my end the confidence intervals do not line up.

Comment: Yes I am running in a new session. Is it possible another package would mess with it?